# Device File Explorer and Database modification time

Tags: android, android-studio

Why the modification time is different between:

Device File Explorer in Android Studio shows 17:18:

[image]

Then I open a path to this DB in Ubuntu and it shows 17:14

[image]

Also, while I am here, it seems like if I open this DB diretly in SqlLiteBrowser and I insert new records > save changs > reload the app the app will not show the changes committed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I get the impression that the Device File Explorer doesn't update its UI in real time based upon filesystem changes.

Comment: This is correct. Once new recrods are inserted I need to click on Synchronize to see the correct modification date.

Comment: Ah! So *that's* what Synchronize does? I couldn't figure out what affect it had, but that makes sense. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Is there a solution for this?  I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the commments section I had to click on Synchronize to see the correct modification date.